# Is there a solid push notification solution for Xamarin that can work properly for China as well as global?

Tags: xamarin, push-notification

I am developing a mobile app for both iOS and Android using Xamarin. This app is intended for global users. I got the challenge finding a working solution of push notification service that can work for both and for China as well as the rest of world.

Here's the things I have explored/tried -

**Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)** - obviously it does not work in China because the connection to google api is blocked.

**Azure Notification Hub** - for Android part it is still leveraging FCM. So it doesn't work. Although there is an option for it to use Baidu push service. But there is no Xamarin SDK support. This is a dead end for me.

**Pushy.ME** - It supports only Xamarin.Android project. I don't find any reference for Xamarin.iOS.

I probably can combine Azure Notification Hub (for iOS), and Pushy (for Android). But I'd like to see if there is any better idea or workaround in one single solution.

Looking forward to brilliant minds.

Comment: If you are ok with Xamarin.Android, you can use the APNS for Xamarin iOS.

Comment: @hashimks, yes, that's what I am implementing now. But I just want to see if anyone knows a universal solution to such scenario.

Comment: What I do is a FCM configuration for Android and Default APNS for iOS.

Comment: FCM does not work for me in China. The initial registration to google api is timed out. It could have resolved both platforms if it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Pushy for Xamarin.Android and Azure Notification Hub for Xamarin.iOS. Although this made things a little bit complex in both apps and my backend.